# Can't add to ArrayLists in the constructor

Tags: java, constructor

The code in the constructor does not get called. I have to invoke an additional function to call the code.

Test Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            SourceClass myClass = new SourceClass();
            myClass.Populate();//If this line is removed it does not work
            System.out.println(myClass.GetDescGroup());

        }
```

Code being tested:

```
 public class SourceClass {

    static ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList> description = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList> descGroup = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

    public void SourceClass () {
        //Does not work.
        String testLine = new String("1 v1 v2 v3");
        String[] testLineSplit = testLine.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < testLineSplit.length;i++) {
            line.add(testLineSplit[i]);
        }

        description.add(line);
        descGroup.add(description);     
    }

    public void Populate() {
        //works
        String testLine = new String("1 v1 v2 v3");
        String[] testLineSplit = testLine.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < testLineSplit.length;i++) {
            line.add(testLineSplit[i]);
        }

        description.add(line);
        descGroup.add(description);
    }

    public String GetDescGroup() {
        return descGroup.get(0).get(0).toString();
    }
}
```

Same code goes in Populate() and SourceClass()

When a function is called to get the ArrayList it just turns up as empty

Comment: Show us complete code.. Where is it working? where is it not working?

Comment: Why do you think you want ArrayList<ArrayList>?

Comment: where is the constructor?

Comment: I'll quickly edit my question so it makes more sense

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Ok I have edited it and should be easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method SourceClass has a return type **void** which  makes it a method and not a constructor. So when you create an object with new SourceClass it calls the default empty constructor

The constructor must be :

```
public SourceClass () {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a constructor, don't give it a return value.

In you code:

```
public void SourceClass () {
    //Does not work.
    String testLine = new String("1 v1 v2 v3");
    String[] testLineSplit = testLine.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < testLineSplit.length;i++) {
        line.add(testLineSplit[i]);
    }

    description.add(line);
    descGroup.add(description);     
}
```

This is NOT a constructor, just a method of the class that has the same name as class and is returning void.

In this case, as Java understands you are NOT providing any constructor, java provides a default one without parameters. In the test code, this default constructor is invoked, not your `SourceClass` method.

To fix it just remove 'void' from the constructor declaration.